# How to dynamically change an app icon, like that of a calendar app, in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for guidance on how to implement a feature in my Flutter app that enables the app icon to change dynamically, resembling the behavior of a calendar app that displays the date as the app icon. If anyone has any code snippets or insights on how to accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Unfortunately, the (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dynamic_icon) package I experimented with is only compatible with iOS.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_icon_flutter